# Listening spring event from tapestry component

Tags: java, spring, events, tapestry

First of all, sorry if I do something wrong, it's my first post on stackOverflow.
Now, my question:

Is it possible to listen to an event thowed by Spring in Tapestry component?
The event (ShopChangedEvent ) is published with ApplicationEventPublisher, from a Spring front service, and i want to listen to this event in a front Tapestry component. 
I tried adding"implements ApplicationListener" to my Tapestry component and overriding the onApplicationEvent method.

Thank for all,

Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it's probably not what you want.

Tapestry components "live" in the scope of HTTP requests. Every time you use a UI component in a TML-markup Tapestry creates just one instance of that component and shares it across all HTTP requests.

So even if you subscribe your UI component to `ApplicationEventPublisher` you won't be able to properly "receive" an event in the right request cycle.